# Do nothing when user does not input anything in the search box

Tags: php, search-engine

How can I make the page do nothing when user does not input anything in the search box?

When it does not have anything in the search box, I want the page to remain the same.

How can I do this?

This is my current code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Brandon's Search Engine
        </title>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //document.getElementById("suggestion")

        function getSuggestion(q) {
            var ajax;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest)//for ie7+, FF, Chrome
                ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();//ajax object
            else
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//for ie6 and previous
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(ajax.status === 200 && ajax.readyState === 4) {
                    //if result are not there then don't display them
                    if(ajax.responseText === "")
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").style.visibility = "visible";
                        document.getElementById("suggestion").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
                }
            };
            ajax.open("GET", "suggestion.php?q=" + q, false);
            ajax.send();
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form method="GET" action="search.php" name="q">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1><center>Brandon's Search Engine</center></h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="text" name="q" style="height: 27px; width: 650px; padding: 2px"
                               onkeyup="getSuggestion(this.value)" autocomplete="off" onblur="blur() document.getElementById('suggestion').style.visibility = 'hidden'"/>

                        <div id="suggestion" style="width: 648px">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" style="height: auto; width: 60px; padding: 2px" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" style="height: auto; width: 50px; padding: 2px" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        To insert your site in result fill in the form at <a href="insert.php">here</a>.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="0" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate your form, like:

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php" name="q" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Your function will be:

```
function validateForm() {
 if(document.getElementById('q').value=='') return false;
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the form submit function like:

Your form will be like:

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php" name="q" id="searchForm">
```

And the script will be like:

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
if($("#q").val() == '')
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

By the way this solution is using JQuery.

Comment: You just have to add an "id" attribute to your form element and an "id" attribute to your search input field. Then add this script in any script tag in your page.